# How to cache all internet downloads

Tags: ubuntu, cache, web

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04. How would I go about caching all downloads? And if Linux does not have this built in, then what are good tools for this?

Please note that this isn't a browser related question, I want any program attempting to access the net to retrieve cached data instead. Also, I am not running a server; I want to do this with a single home PC.

Comment: This sounds very difficult or impossible do to for "_all_ internet downloads", although it should be possible if you limit your scope (ie. only http requests)

Comment: @lk I'm aiming at caching http and apt-get requests

Comment: I found a program named apt-proxy. Its purpose is specifically to cache apt downloads on a network. It can be found [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/338)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a caching web proxy like [polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) or [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). Although it's called a proxy-server you don't need a separate system to run it. It just means that it is a special software that can serve a client a particular service (In this case caching already downloaded data). A client is also a software that can run on the same system as the server or request the service remotely.

In your case i recommend `polipo`. You can find it in the ubuntu repository. Just install it and set the proxy-server in your browser settings to

```
localhost:8123
```

of course you can request data with other software than a browser over the proxy, too.

Comment: I tried polipo, and it works like a charm. Thanks :)